PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 5): 835
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
While stepping out of the UK's National Gallery this morning, I remembered that I meant to design a card with a special greeting to some friends and neighbours. Here's what I came up with:


For whom is the message?
What is the message?

EXTRA CREDIT: Why did I select today for this puzzle?

For those wondering about the extra credit question rot13(Gur chmmyr znexf gur yvtugvat bs gur Gensnytne Fdhner Puevfgznf Gerr, juvpu vf na naahny tvsg gb gur HX sebz bhe sevraqf naq arvtuobhef va Abejnl).

What is the significance of the number in the title?

@caPNCApn https://xkcd.com/835/

The presents below the tree

 spell NORGE (the Norwegian word for Norway), using nautical signal flags.

The tree itself

 is a Morse Code tree:


 The lines spell the following (in CMYK order, like printer ink):
 Cyan: GOD
 Magenta: JUL
 Yellow: TIL
 Black: DEG

So the message is

 "God jul til deg" - Norwegian for "Merry Christmas to you"!


I looked for the reason for today in particular - my best guess was that it was related to the Yule celebration and the old Germanic calendar - but couldn't find anything.

Good work! However you have one letter wrong. BTW have you ever been to the National Gallery?

Ah.. (rot13)Puevfgznf ng Gensnytne Fdhner...

@Deusovi If you correct the flaggo, I'll award the check mark.

@DanielS Oops, fixed! I kept looking at it and thinking "Yes, that's definitely an N, not an M..."

how should the CMYK order be understood? I'm new to morse puzzling.

@ssssaaaa It means that the Cyan ribbon/tinsel should be read first, then the Magenta ribbon/tinsel, then the Yellow ribbon/tinsel, then the blacK ribbon/tinsel. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model

ahh, forgot to check the original image when I read the answer :)
